# select linked rows in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I'm creating a branching dialog game, and used a dialog tool that outputs JSON with a `link` and a `link_path` to connect dialogs together. I've parsed and inserted this structure in PostgreSQL.

I want to query a subset of rows, let's say starting with row 1, and follow the `link_path` until the `link_path` is null. Successive rows may be out of order.

For example, in the table below,

- starting with row 1, I find row with `link_path = b`,
- this gives me row 3, I find row with `link_path = c`,
- this gives me row 4, row 4's `link_path` is `null`, so we return this set: `[row 1, row 3, row 4]`

--

```
link     link_path    info
--------------------------
a          b          asdjh
w          y          akhaq
b          c          uiqwd
c                     isado
y          z          qwiuu
z                     nzabo
```

In PostgreSQL, how can I select rows like this without creating a loop of queries? My goal is performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select t.* from mytable t where link = 'a'
    union all
    select t.*
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.link = c.link_path
)
select * from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=06515cab64b6f49b60d61a03b50f43d3)**:

```
link | link_path | info 
:--- | :-------- | :----
a    | b         | asdjh
b    | c         | uiqwd
c    | null      | isado
```

Comment: Is the recursive nature of this query more performant than individual selects row by row?

Comment: @Growler: this will be more efficient than running multiple queries. For your data structure, a recursive query seems like the relevant approach. But basically, it is hard to query such structure really efficiently. There are other ways to represent hierarchical data that you might want to look at. See this SO post for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database